# JqueryMobile - Device Orientation changes

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, google-visualization

I'm trying to build a mobile dashboard app, if the charts are loaded in portrait mode, when the user changes to landscape mode, i'm re-drawing the chart to fit the charts to landscape width. it works fine.

I want to know is there any better way to solve orientation changes? without re-drawing every time? the charts are coming from external sources like google charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the Google Visualization API charts, no, there is no better solution, as chart dimensions are fixed at the time the chart is drawn.